# Does Zero-copy exist in Windows OS?

Tags: windows, zero-copy

Reading [this zero copy article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/),

Does Zero-copy exist in Windows OS (server 2003, 2008, 2008 R2) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is supported via [the `TransmitFile` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm pretty sure that IIS uses this as well.

Whether or not this method does real zero-copy (i.e. doesn't even copy from the file buffers to the socket buffers) is not explicitly mentioned in the documentation. But given the fact that this method is defined in a way that **definitely** makes it possible, I'd be highly surprised if this were not the case.

The closest the documentation comes to stating it clearly is this paragraph:

> [...] `TransmitFile` achieves its performance gains by sending data directly from the file cache.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. I wonder if TransmitFile() copy the data from kernel-read-buffer to socket-buffer and to NIC buffer ? or does it copy the data straight from kernel-read-buffer to NIC buffer ?