# What does MmMapLockedPages do in UserMode?

Tags: winapi, nt-native-api

EDIT: while browsing on StackOverflow, I discovered [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff566416(v=vs.85)) and that was not yielded by any google searches or documentation trawling, as it’s under “Previous Versions” of the documentation - does that mean access to this function is deprecated? Why isn’t it in updated documentation, and are there any downsides to using this over [VirtualAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc)?

Anyway, this makes my question fairly obsolete, but I still want to understand what [MmMapLockedPages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmmaplockedpages) really does when AccessMode = UserMode.

OP:
I have read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45573419/12962917) that a kernel driver can map space it’s allocated in system memory into user memory, with [MmMapLockedPages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-mmmaplockedpages). From what I can find in the documentation, there aren’t any other (documented) NT API kernel-mode functions one can use to “put” memory to user space virtual memory.
I want to know whether that mapping allows the user to have some kind of viewing to the memory but that memory is still in system space, or if there is a “mapped” chunk of memory of the same size in user space that’s completely accessible by the caller, as if that memory had been malloc’d.

My understanding of the memory systems is far from good, so excuse any misuse of terminology!

Comment: No idea why google didn't give you a match, my first result is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff566416(v=vs.85) and that page doesn't say anything about the function being deprecated or otherwise unavailable.

Comment: in what question ? what problem call `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` ?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir why is it in “previous versions” do you know?

Comment: No idea, I've only ever done kernel programming as a hobby and not since XP.